# Use kCGBlendModeClear to implement eraser stroke on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I use the kCGBlendModeClear blend mode to implement eraser tools. It works fine in ios, but not working in OS X. It creates a black color line with the kCGBlendModeClear blend mode in OS X.

Here's sample code:

```
  #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  #else
    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
  #endif

  CGContextSaveGState(context);

  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, 200);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);

  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 150, 150);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 180, 180);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);

  CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

iOS:

[image: in iOS]

but in OS X:

[image: in OS X]

I also tried change the view and superview opaque property and background color, but no help.

I know the clear color is actually black with an alpha 0, but I wonder why the alpha is ignored in OS X.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Answer (score 1):

Use Layer backed NSView, [view setWantsLayer:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours.

Use NSBezierPath to clip, in case of NSView clipping

Using "kCGBlendModeClear" needs to set "self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];".

I guess we can't set backgroundColor of NSView. Otherwise, we have to adjust the context of the NSView. But, I don't know how to.

Just using NSBezierPath clip. It's easy...